# Android TextView.setText working only sometimes inside Runnable

Tags: java, android, runnable, settext

I have a postDelayed Runnable that counts down from 3 the executes some code x number of times. I am displaying text to the user via setText(). The setText() function works in some areas of an if,else if,else but does not work in other areas.

```
    final Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if ((--count != 0) && (gestureCounter != selectedItems.size())) {
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                liveView.setText("Do " + selectedItems.get(gestureCounter) + " in " + String.valueOf(count));//works
            }
            else if(gestureCounter != selectedItems.size()){
                count=4;//3 seconds + 1
                liveView.setText("Hold " + selectedItems.get(gestureCounter));//NOT WORKING
                mHandler.post(this);
                fcalc.setTrain(true);
                while(fcalc.getTrain()){
                    //wait till trainig is done
                }
                gestureCounter++;
            }
            else{
                liveView.setText("");//works
                fcalc.Train();
                fcalc.setClassify(true);
            }
        }
    };
    mHandler.post(r1);
```

Please take a look at my comments to see which setText() functions work or don't. The one in the else if is the only one that is not working.

Any ideas?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried debugging to find out is your runnable was even executed when setText() doesn't calls?

Comment: When you say "not working", what do you mean? Also, the "else if" has `mHandler.post(this)` which will not delay instead of `mHandler.postDelayed(this,1000)` which will delay one second. Is that what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of you are calling `mHandler.post(this);` this will call immediately the handler runnable again and also you are incrementing the value `gestureCounter`, so next time will come to this loop and it will go to first loop or 3rd loop as per condition

Try to add delay in that loop also and check

Edited:

Because of your while loop continuously running, UI is not updating, Just comment that and run the code like below condition it will work fine

like this

```
                    else if(gestureCounter != selectedItems.size()){
                    liveView.setText("Hold " +
                            selectedItems.get(gestureCounter));//NOT WORKING

                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // delay added 

                    if(fcalc.getTrain()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    count=4;//3 seconds + 1

//                    fcalc.setTrain(true);
//                    while(fcalc.getTrain()){
//                        //wait till trainig is done
//                    }
                    gestureCounter++;
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, this produces no change. The delay isn't waiting.

Comment: may I know the value of your count, gestureCounter and selectedItems.size() at beginning..?

Comment: count=4, gesturecounter=0, selectedItems.size()=3. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer have a look If you have any doubt let me know.

Comment: I see what you are going for but the while loop is necessary to wait until a different process is complete, the amount of time that this process takes varies so I can't predict it with a postDelay.